# How to limit the maximum size of a Map by removing oldest entries when limit reached

Tags: java, caching, collections, dictionary

I want an implementation of Map that has a maximum size. I want to use this as a cache and so oldest entries are removed once limit has been reached.

I also don't want to introduce a dependency on any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Why don't you want a dependency on 3rd party libs ? I'd much rather use a well-designed/well-tested lib for something like this rather than expend the effort building and testing my own

Comment: so what did you try and what error did you get ? this is a do-my-homework question

Comment: I'm writing a small library and I'm trying to avoid having to enforce dependencies or add unnecessary bulk.

Comment: I'm not getting an error, I just wanted advice on how others would tackle this problem. It's not homework.

Comment: Would be better that you presented us with what you tried, or how you think you should go about this rather than just straight out asking for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev, I posted the question and my own answer at the same time. I was happy with my solution when I wrote it so wanted to post it here purely to share it with others (after not finding a satisfactory answer here). A better solution was proposed and I learnt something. Fantastic! I thought the requirements were concise. Can you explain how I could have done things better or why this isn't useful to others?

Comment: Is it because I started with "I want..." rather than "how do I..."?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) like this

You can remove by LRU or FIFO.

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> createLRUMap(final int maxEntries) {
    return new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(maxEntries*10/7, 0.7f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxEntries;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: why you did not use WeakHashMap?

Comment: Using a WeakHashMap as a cache has two problems. 1) it has no upper limit in size 2) it can be cleared all at once, it has no limit to how much will be cleared on a GC.

Comment: This is perfect, I did not know about that feature of LinkedHashMap. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter: Why did you make initialCapacity bigger than maxCapacity?

Comment: @WaleryStrauch HashMap and LinkedHashMap resize when the load factor is reached. e.g. say you set it to `128`, it will double in size which you reach `128*0.7f`.  One solution is to make the capacity `maxEntries*10/7` or use a load factor of `1.0f`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Oh sorry, my question was: Why not just put `maxEntries` to initialCapacity. Like this: `new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(maxEntries, 0.7f, true)`. In this case second arg dosen't mean anything

Comment: @WaleryStrauch if you do that and put in maxEntries, it may resize needlessly. It is better to give it a capacity where it won't resize if you put maxEntries in.

Comment: @WaleryStrauch BTW a HashMap always has a capacity of a power of 2 in reality, i.e. it rounds up to a power of 2

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that just wraps a normal HashMap and delegates the method calls to it.
The only difference is that the Map cannot grow beyond the maximum capacity.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public class CacheMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private final Map<K, V> delegate = new HashMap<K, V>();
    private Queue<K> keyInsertionOrder = new LinkedList<K>();
    private final int maxCapacity;

    public CacheMap(int maxCapacity) {
        if (maxCapacity < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Capacity must be greater than 0");
        }
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        delegate.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return delegate.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return delegate.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return delegate.entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return delegate.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return delegate.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return delegate.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return delegate.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return delegate.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V previous = delegate.put(key, value);
        keyInsertionOrder.remove(key);
        keyInsertionOrder.add(key);

        if (delegate.size() > maxCapacity) {
            K oldest = keyInsertionOrder.poll();
            delegate.remove(oldest);
        }
        return previous;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (K key : m.keySet()) {
            put(key, m.get(key));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        keyInsertionOrder.remove(key);
        return delegate.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return delegate.values();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a personal class which does what you need. Once the map is full, oldest accessed objects are removed when inserting. It uses a hashmap and a linked list.

You have two methods to read :

- peek (which doesn't mark the object as recently accessed)
- get (which mark the object as recently accessed and thus prevents its removal for a time)

Here's the class (comments removed because they were in French) :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public final class HashCache<K, T> {

    public interface Disposer<T> {
        void dispose(T t);
    }

    class Maillon {
        public K cle;

        public Maillon precedent;
        public Maillon suivant;
        public T contenu;
    }

    private Map<K, Maillon> barrette = new HashMap<K, Maillon>();

    private Maillon sommet;
    private Maillon fond;
    private int tailleCache = 100;

    private Disposer<T> disposer;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public HashCache(int tailleCache) {
        if (tailleCache>2) this.tailleCache = tailleCache;
        Maillon[] maillons = new HashCache.Maillon[tailleCache];
        sommet = maillons[0] = new Maillon();
        for (int i=1; i<tailleCache; i++) (maillons[i-1].suivant = maillons[i] = new Maillon()).precedent = maillons[i-1];
        fond = maillons[tailleCache-1];
        //check();
    }

    public Object getLastRead() {
        return sommet.contenu;
    }

    public Object peek(K cle) {
        Object m = barrette.get(cle);
        if (m==null) return null;
        return ((Maillon) m).contenu;
    }

    public synchronized void remove(K cle) {
        Maillon m = (Maillon) barrette.remove(cle);
        if (m!=null) {
            if (disposer!=null) disposer.dispose(m.contenu);
            m.contenu = null;
            m.precedent.suivant = m.suivant;
            m.suivant.precedent = m.precedent;
            fond.suivant = m;
            m.precedent = fond;
            fond = m;
        }
    }


    public synchronized Object put(K cle, T valeur) {
        if (cle==null) return valeur;

        if (fond.cle!=null) {
            barrette.remove(fond.cle);
            if (disposer!=null) disposer.dispose(fond.contenu);
        }
        fond.cle = cle;
        barrette.put(cle, fond);
        fond.contenu = valeur;
        fond.suivant = sommet;
        sommet.precedent = fond;
        sommet = fond;
        fond = fond.precedent;
        fond.suivant = null;

        return valeur;
    }

    public int computeDepth(K cle) {
        Maillon m = sommet;
        for (int i=0; i<tailleCache; i++) {
            if (cle.equals(m.cle)) return i;
            m=m.suivant;
            if (m==null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public synchronized void removeAll() {
        if (disposer!=null) {
            for (Maillon m : barrette.values()) {
                disposer.dispose(m.contenu);
            }
        }
        barrette = new HashMap<K, Maillon>();
        Maillon[] t = new HashCache.Maillon[tailleCache];
        sommet = t[0] = new Maillon();
        for (int i=1; i<tailleCache; i++) (t[i-1].suivant = t[i] = new Maillon()).precedent = t[i-1];
        fond = t[tailleCache-1];
    }


    public synchronized T get(K cle) {
        Maillon m = barrette.get(cle);
        if (m == sommet) return m.contenu;
        if (m == null) return null;
        if (m == fond) {
            m.precedent.suivant = null;
            m.suivant = sommet;
            sommet.precedent = m;
            sommet = m;
            fond = m.precedent;
            m.precedent = null;
        } else {
            m.suivant.precedent = m.precedent;
            m.precedent.suivant = m.suivant;
            m.suivant = sommet;
            sommet.precedent = m;
            sommet = m;
        }
        return m.contenu;
    }

    public Disposer<T> getDisposer() {
        return disposer;
    }

    public void setDisposer(Disposer<T> disposer) {
        this.disposer = disposer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you chose not to implement the Map interface?

Comment: Yes. But a bad one : When I made this class, about 15 years ago, even HashMap didn't exist (we had Hashtable). I made a few changes later, among them the generics, but implementing Map would be good too. I just didn't need it until now.

Answer (score 0):

If this *isn't* homework, I would strongly recommend using a third-party library to avoid the pain of designing, testing and maintaining your own solutuion.

See the [Guava MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) mechanism, for example.

Comment: I would normally, but I'm strongly trying to avoid introducing dependencies as I am writing a small library. Thanks for alerting me to MapMaker, very handy and I shall use that in my larger projects.